# why use Fastlane gym for WatchOS app failure

Tags: fastlane, watchos

I used gym command to build the watch app after setting up project with proper provisioning profiles and identifiers. I am able to see ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED message on gym output and there are errors failures from verbose log, but it is not able to Continue running, then the timeout failed?The program hangs on the last line and reports an error:Too long with no output (exceeded 10m0s).

Issue Detail Link:https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/13996

```
lane :beta do |values|
  match(type: 'adhoc', readonly: false, force_for_new_devices: true, force: true,app_identifier ["com.clarify.Carepilot-beta", "com.clarify.Carepilot-beta.watchkitapp", "com.clarify.Carepilot-beta.watchkitapp.watchextension"])
  gym(scheme: 'Carepilot - ADHOC', export_method: 'ad-hoc')
end
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like you're running on a CI system like Travis CI or Circle CI? Simply give it a longer timeout.

Comment: Yes,I run fastlane gym command on Circle CI, but it timed out, I suspect there is a problem with my fastlane match gym command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `no_output_timeout` parameter in your circleci config:

```
- run:  
    command: YOUR_FASTLANE_COMMAND
    no_output_timeout: 30m
```

See https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007188574-Build-has-hit-timeout-limit

Comment: Thank you! I will try now!
my fix:
- run:
          name: Fastlane
          command: bundle exec fastlane $FASTLANE_LANE
          no_output_timeout: 30m